# Python imageio and visvis draws lines

Tags: python, arrays, image, keras, python-imageio

I'm new to python
My problem is that imageio and visvis draws vertical lines instead of pixel, what's wrong?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9o3l.png)

```
def writePic(picnum,picres):
  return vv.imwrite('\picsout\pic'+str(picnum)+'.png',np.array(np.uint8(picres)))
def dothisandthat(pnum):
 global rewards,reward
 pictime=time.time()
 tphase=pnum>4
 imin=readPic(pnum)
 imout=[[[255,255,255]]*len(imin[0])]*len(imin)
 for i in range(len(imin)):
    for j in range(len(imin[i])):
        obsP=obsPixels(i,j,imin)
        if tphase:
            train()
            fcol=find_col(obsP,pnum)
        else:
            fcol=random_trainer()
        imout[i][j]=fcol
        reward=calcRew(i,j,imin,fcol)
        rewards.append(reward)
        obs1,obs2,obs3,obs4,obs5=obsP
        remember_recdata([*fcol,*obs1,*obs2,*obs3,*obs4,*obs5,pnum])
        if True:
            writePic(pnum,imout)
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you were hoping to draw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed it by replacing `imout=[[[255,255,255]]*len(imin[0])]*len(imin)` with `imout=np.zeros((len(imin),len(imin[0]),3))`